# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file (.css, .png , .html)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am integrating react into Django, here is the error I get.

```
ERROR in ./backend/frontend/src/App.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .App {
|   text-align: center;
| }
 @ ./backend/frontend/src/App.js 2:0-19
 @ ./backend/frontend/src/index.js 4:0-24 6:107-110
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
        ]

    }

};
```

and here is my package.json dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.55.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
```

Can someone please suggest how to fix this error on how to fix this? Thanks

**Solution**

Turns out I had to alot of things missing, here is what I did:

```
npm i react react-dom --save-dev
npm install -D style-loader css-loader sass-loader
npm install --save axios
npm install --save react-router-dom
npm install --save react-dropzone
npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.1.1
npm i web-vitals --save-dev
npm install url-loader --save-dev
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

And then updated my `webpack.config.js` according to the top answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS ReactJs - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911599/css-reactjs-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-curre)

Comment: Essentially, you need a separate rule to handle `css` files - currently you only have one set up for `scss`. Unless you have extra dependencies not shown, you are also missing all the style/css/sass loaders.

Comment: @lawrence-witt nope that question did not help. Can you please post a suggested solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your `package.json` already contains them under `dependencies`, install the missing loaders:

```
npm install -D style-loader css-loader sass-loader
```

Add a new rule to your webpack config to target `css` files:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```